# What's the best way for a self-learner to prepare for Richard Courant's Calculus Book?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I'm a software developer looking to make a career switch to Mechanical Engineering (at least I think so). My interests lie in design, complex systems, maglev, rockets, and new forms of space propulsion. Before I really commit myself to University, I would like to get my feet wet in Physics/Engineering. Most likely I'd major in Applied Physics or Engineering Physics.

Ultimately, my goal is to get through [Fundamental University Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0006BNQDG) by Alonso & Finn and then to get through [Shigley's Mechanical Engineering Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073398209). Alonso's text seems to require some heavy duty calculus, and Courant's calculus book seems to have a lot of practical application problems so I think the two would complement one another.

The only problem is, I'm not exactly sure what kind of precalculus prep I would need for that. [Principles of Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007001390X) by Allendoerfer looks to be a rigorous and proof-focused trek through precalculus, but I'm not sure that this would be the best book for me if my preferences lean towards the more practical.

Generally, to prep myself for calculus I've been following a rough outline of what many here have already suggested:

Algebra:

- *Elementary Algebra* by Jacobs
- *Algebra* by Gelfand
- *Functions and Graphs* by Gelfand

Geometry:

- *Geometry (2nd Edition)* by Jacobs
- *Geometry Revisited* by Coxeter

Trigonometry:

- *Trigonometry* by Gelfand

General:

- *What is Mathematics?* by Courant

Now, how should I handle this whole precalculus thing? I skimmed through Addison-Wesley's *Algebra and Trigonometry* and I love that it's replete with practical-looking problems and novel facts about the given subtopic but it feels like a "plug and chug" type book. And as cool as calculating the parabolic cross sections of a car's headlights seems, problems like these feel cheap and trivial.

So what's a good precalculus book for the aspiring Applied Physicist / Engineer? Should I just stick with [Principles of Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007001390X)?. Or should I replace that with [Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592441300) or Serge Lang's *Basic Mathematics*? What would best prepare me for Courant's book and beyond, given my goals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courant's book has proofs and theory in it, so you should read a better algebra book than Jacobs (except if you've *never* studied any algebra at all), perhaps *Basic Mathematics* by Lang as you suggest.

Lang's book will give you enough geometry too, including some discussion of vectors. There's no need to read a whole geometry book. *Geometry Revisited* is difficult and is not useful for calculus. It covers material that would rarely if ever be needed for physics.

You don't really need to consider *What is Mathematics?* a prerequisite—read that for enjoyment only.

I don't particularly like the book by Allendoerfer (if it's the one I'm thinking of). It's not entirely rigorous. It introduces some advanced concepts, but then studies them very superficially. My recollection is that at times it also accepts some statements without proof but without even mentioning that fact.

The books by Gelfand are a great idea, particularly *Algebra* and *Functions and Graphs*. *The Method of Coordinates* is also good. The trigonometry book is okay but not terrific. It seems to have been written mainly by the American coauthor and is dumbed down compared to Gelfand's trig book in Russian. (The others are actual translations.) Again, *Basic Mathematics* is likely to be enough here, but if not, you also have other choices, such as *Trigonometry* by Nobbs (which you can read after the trigonometry sections of Lang).

One thing I would add to this list is an introductory book on inequalities, since those come up a lot in proofs in calculus. *Introduction to Inequalities* by Beckenbach and Bellman is good for that.

Another possibility, though not strictly necessary, would be an introduction to vector geometry beyond what's contained in Lang's book. For example, *Elementary Vector Algebra* by Macbeath. This isn't really important for single-variable calculus, but it's important for physics and for multivariable calculus. You can put this off until later if you like.

One last point I'd make is that one possible consideration when choosing between Courant, Apsotol and Spivak is that Spivak has a complete solution manual. Even if these books differ in some ways, they're more alike than they are different, so the solution manual could make Spivak worth it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The Allendoerfer book you may or may not be thinking of is the one which introduces set theory and logic in its opening chapters. One of the primary reasons I'm drawn to it is because I've read that if you can get through this book and go through all the problems then Courant or Spivak will be no problem. 

Will Lang and the supplementary books you've suggested prepare me in the same way? I have skimmed through the first chapter of Courant's books and I'm not understanding anything at all. To be fair my knowledge of math is very elementary.

Comment: Lang's book will give you enough background to learn calculus. Certainly it's enough for non-rigorous calculus books. For books that give complete proofs and focus on theory, such as Spivak, Apostol and Courant, some people will need additional preparation and some won't. Gelfand's books are good because they contain harder problems on basic algebra and functions, so they get you thinking in the way you need to for rigorous calculus. Apart from the basic material in Lang, what you need isn't specific mathematical knowledge, but the habit of thinking about math in the right way. Gelfand's...

Comment: books provide much *better* preparation for rigorous higher math than does Allendoerfer and Oakley, in my opinion. I certainly don't believe the claim that going through Allendoerfer's book will make the problems in Spivak or Courant easy. That's a bit crazy. Another good book, if you have time, would be *The Mathematics of Choice* by Niven, not for the specific facts in it, which aren't central to calculus, but because it provides additional "mathematical maturity" and the material is useful and interesting in its own right.

Comment: To summarize, what you need for rigorous calculus is the material in Lang plus a degree of mathematical maturity.

Comment: Thank you once again. I'm going to use Lang as a primary textbook after I finish Jacob's Algebra/Geometry and Algebra 2 with Gelfand's text. I will get every book you have recommended and use that as supplementary texts. I think what I was lacking is a central book which exposes me to the fundamental ideas I have to learn and the problem sets to really re-enforce them. It seems that Lang supplemented by Gelfand and the other texts you suggested will help me lots.

Comment: I would go to a university library and have a look at the books before spending a lot of money on them. While you're there, you might also see other books that you prefer.

Comment: So I believe these are the things I need to master before moving on to Courant. Algebra (Being able to factor expressions and equations like it was second nature e.g. expressions with rational components). Solving linear, quadratic, equations. Know all the most basic functions and their transformations and the graphs of all these. Formula manipulation. Mastering the 6 main trig functions. So I think that indeed, Gelfand's texts in particular will help me to become more comfortable with manipulating expressions and playing around with functions.

Comment: One last point. Studying calculus at the level of Courant's book takes a lot of motivation and a degree of mathematical ability. Many people are successful engineers despite having learned calculus at a non-rigorous level. So if you find that rigorous math is too hard, it would be okay, after Lang's book, to study calculus from an easier source.

Comment: I'm also studying very basic physics books designed to build my intuition (e.g. Thinking Physics) so I will approach these as well with the problems that arise in that book always in the back of my mind. Just curious though how you recommend tackling functions? It's a supplementary chapter in Lang's book as far as I know and Gelfand's book on functions extends your knowledge rather than builds it from scratch as far as I know. So when should I actually skip ahead to that chapter and read that particular book?

Comment: It depends on your background knowledge. If you've learned the material from Part 1 of Lang's book, it's possible to skip ahead and read Chapter 13. Gelfand's *Functions and Graphs* is mostly self-contained on what a function is, but it will be difficult to do the problems if you're not already very comfortable with algebra. Also, *The Method of Coordinates* is on basic analytic geometry, and it logically precedes *Functions and Graphs*.

Comment: By the way, *PSSC Physics* is a great introduction to physics at a pre-calculus level. If you feel you're learning a lot from Jacobs' book, then, yes, continue with that. Otherwise, you could probably start with Lang now.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Perhaps I'm preparing entirely wrong as well because my end goal is to master Alonso and Finn's Fundamental University Physics rather than Courant's Calculus book. My goal really is to be able to go through BOA's Mathematical Physics book afterwards and be able to get through Irodov's Problem's in Physics. If I find Courant too difficult I'll switch to Calculus an Intuitive Approach.

Comment: If Courant/Apostol/Spivak is too difficult, you could also try *A First Course in Calculus* by Lang, or *Calculus* by Marsden and Weinstein.  Those are at a level that is intermediate between a fully rigorous book and one like Kline, which is the book I think you're talking about.: http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/calculus-an-intuitive-and-physical-approach

Comment: I think I will go with an introductory text like Kline's before moving onto Courant. I like the idea of building intuition through constant and practical application especially in a mostly physics context. I will probably hop between the two and use Spivak's problems to work through since his book comes with a solutions manual. That review you linked to me only reinforces my hunch that I really need to master Calculus, whatever that means. I do think I'm starting to figure out what I do need to know and the course track that you've helped me build I think will get me to where I want to go.

Comment: Can't thank you enough!

Comment: I don't think you need to decide this now. You should keep working on precalculus topics and then make your decision based on where you are when you want to start calculus. Your proficiency in algebra will probably be the main determining factor in deciding what level to study calculus at. If you're capable of learning math to a high level, then you should do it, because this will make your appreciation of physics much better. What I'm saying is that if you reach a point later on where you think that level isn't achievable for you, then you can reevaluate your goals.